# OSM linestring shown as point

Tags: gdal, openstreetmap, geometry, ogr, linestring

I have loaded the following file http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/coastlines to postgreSQL. In visual studio with gdal/ogr and geos enabled:
SELECT geom 
FROM waterpoly
WHERE geom IS NOT NULL LIMIT 10;

Stored the result in std::vector* multigeom;

In a for loop

```
OGRGeometry* geo  =  multigeom->at(i);
printf("geo type: %ld \n",geo->getGeometryType());
```

I expected it to be 'wkbMultiLineString' (because it says line strings in the above osm website) but the answer was  'wkbPoint'.

Regardless, I have done the following:

```
OGRMultiLineString* mult = (OGRMultiLineString*) multigeom->at(i);
for( int j = 0; j < mult->getNumGeometries() ; j++ ) 
{
OGRGeometry* geogeom =  (OGRGeometry*) mult->getGeometryRef(j);
printf("geo type: %ld \n",geogeom->getGeometryType());
```

}

Answer was 'wkbunknown'

Can anybody give me the reason behind this? or am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: How did you load the data into postgres? Did you use osm2pgsql, osmosis for loading.

Comment: I used pgAdminIII->Plugins->PostGIS shapefile and DBF loader 2.0

Answer (score 1):

If I add the shapefile directly to QGIS, it is of type "line" and named "lines" (not "waterpoly").

Why don't you use the "official" coastline shapefile from http://tile.openstreetmap.org/processed_p.tar.bz2? Or http://tile.openstreetmap.org/shoreline_300.tar.bz2 for a first try with reduced resolution. Those are polygons.

You have to specify EPSG:3857 as srid, because the .prj file is missing.

See http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Coastline for details.

Comment: You're right. Table name is 'lines'. I have updated the question. Unfortunately, with the above code, the results are as I mentioned above.

I am going to try the link you've provided now and will let you know. I am working on to find the location of intersection a vessel's predicted path with the coastline. I believe polygon type should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

OpenStreetMap Stores data in different way than other GIS formats.The coordinates are stored in nodes(points in other gis) and ways(lines and polygons) reference these nodes. Unlike linestring, which are array of coordinates, **Ways in openstreetmap do not store coordinates in them**. Hence you **must use** the OpenStreetMap tools like **osm2pgsql or osmosis** to load data into postgis.

Comment: That applies to Openstreetmap raw data, but the site mentioned offers GIS compatible shapefiles.